# Data Frame Mapping in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a data set like below

```
INo,Sc,Desc,Quan,IDate,UPice,CID,Country
1,2,"H,H",6,12-1-2010 8:26,2.55,c1,United Kingdom
2,3,"WE,RN",6,12-1-2010 8:26,3.39,c2,United Kingdom
3,3,CREAM ,8,12-1-2010 8:26,2.75,c3,United Kingdom
4,4,KLE,6,12-1-2010 8:26,3.39,c4,United Kingdom
5,5,"DI,AMR,ROR, ",2,1-7-2011 13:55,11.02,c5,United Kingdom
6,6,SU"asasa,1,12-9-2010 16:26,11.02,c6,United Kingdom
```

I have created Data frame by executing below code:

```
case class Rating(CID: String, SC: String, rating: Double)
def parseRating(str: String): Rating = {
val fields = str.split(",")
Rating(fields(6), fields(1), 1.0D)
}
val ratings = spark.read.textFile("C:/Users/test/Desktop/test123.txt").map(parseRating).toDF().dropDuplicates("CID", "SC")
ratings.collect().map(t => println(t))
ratings.show()
```

I am getting output like below

```
+---------------+---+------+
|            CID| SC|rating|
+---------------+---+------+
|12-9-2010 16:26|  6|   1.0|
|             c3|  3|   1.0|
|            CID| Sc|   1.0|
|             c4|  4|   1.0|
|           3.39|  3|   1.0|
|              2|  5|   1.0|
|           2.55|  2|   1.0|
+---------------+---+------+
```

Here I came to because of `field=str.split(",")`.input data is
6,6,"SET,CO,SU",1,12-9-2010 16:26,11.02,c6,United Kingdom

But my expected output is

```
+---------------+---+------+
|            CID| SC|rating|
+---------------+---+------+
|             c6|  6|   1.0|
|             c3|  3|   1.0|
|             c2|  3|   1.0|
|             c4|  4|   1.0|
|             c5|  5|   1.0|
|             c1|  2|   1.0|
+---------------+---+------+
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Use Spark's inbuilt CSV Reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spark 2, you can do it like below:

```
val data = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("test123.txt")
data.select("CID", "Sc").withColumn("rating", lit(1.0)).show
+---+---+------+
|CID| Sc|rating|
+---+---+------+
| c1|  2|   1.0|
| c2|  3|   1.0|
| c3|  3|   1.0|
| c4|  4|   1.0|
| c5|  5|   1.0|
| c6|  6|   1.0|
+---+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly split the each record with ",". since some of the column value has got "," as a value not as separator. e.g "H,H" in the first record,

You will need a regex to do the splitting as below,

```
def parseRating(str: String): Rating = {
val fields = str.split("\\,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
Rating(fields(6), fields(1), 1.0D)
}
```

Also, your first line is the header.Read it with header true while loading the data file or filter the first line once its loaded.

Comment: Hi Amit,thanks for quick reply. after applying above code it working as expected but i am getting header also as one row "|CID| Sc|  1.0|" .please let me know how to avoid this.

Comment: As i have mentioned in the post you need to filter the first record once it is loaded, you can put a filter transformation  before performing map transformation

Comment: Hi Amit, if data set is  like "536477,22041,RECORD FRAME 7" SINGLE SIZE ,48,12-1-2010 12:27,2.1,16210,United Kingdom" i am getting" Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6" exception

Comment: if i put my old code it isn't throwing any exception

Comment: 536477,22041,RECORD FRAME 7" SINGLE SIZE ,48,12-1-2010 12:27,2.1,16210,United Kingdom

Comment: @Sai Kumar, Do you think people are here to give the solution for the entire scenario without you mentioning in the question. I have given the solution for the data set that you posted in the question and as you said in the first comment it worked for you. If you are getting different scenario, you need to update the question and as well show the efforts that you put to solve it. You should have given thought before down voting the answer. Weather it matched with the question you asked or not.